How to fix this error that blocks upgrading jammy -> noble?
Normal updates go through just fine, but the release-upgrade to the next LTS does not.
Fortunately, I'm using do-release-upgrade under the script(1) command, so I capture the output. It's too long to put the whole thing here.  The short version is that there's a complaint about a GitHub credential, and then the upgrade backs out to the original state.
But there's another problem to mention first: the output suggests web pages for getting help on Ubuntu sites.  But the one I looked at suggested using an app called 'xchat',
but when I use the apt-get command suggested for installing it, the app does not appear to exist (in my Xubuntu Jammy).  So gave up on the Ubuntu direct help, and I'm hoping for a better answer here.
I don't know why the problem occurs, or even what has actually gone wrong, so I could use help both with diagnosis and with a fix.
Here's the complaint with a little context:
Reading state information... Done
Get:1ahttps://cli.github.com/packageststablerInReleaseu[3,917[B]itingafornheaders]aders]]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntuojammyrInReleaseu.com] [Waiting for headers]
Hit https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/debestable.InReleasem] [Waiting for headers]
Err https://cli.github.com/packagesnstableeInReleaseuntu.com]
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 23F3D4EA75716059 GitHub CLI <opensource+cli@github.com>
```Reading state information... Done
Get:1ahttps://cli.github.com/packageststablerInReleaseu[3,917[B]itingafornheaders]aders]]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntuojammyrInReleaseu.com] [Waiting for headers]
Hit https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/debestable.InReleasem] [Waiting for headers]
Err https://cli.github.com/packagesnstableeInReleaseuntu.com]
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 23F3D4EA75716059 GitHub CLI <opensource+cli@github.com>

Then
Third party sources disabled

Some third party entries in your sources.list were disabled. You can
re-enable them after the upgrade with the 'software-properties' tool
or your package manager.

To continue please press [ENTER]

Then after some downloading, the failure is announced:
Hit[http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntuonoble-security.InRelease125.190.80)]]
Hit[http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76-dev/stable/ubuntu noble InRelease
Fetchedk0nB]in 0s (0 B/s)

Error during update

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of
network problem, please check your network connection and retry.


Restoring original system state

I did not see a network problem.  My usual test is "ping 8.8.8.8" which pings a Google server, is easy to remember, and seems a decent test of connectivity minus the domain-name servers.
So how do I find out what's really wrong and how to fix it?

Use ppa-purge to remove all 3rd party repos and the software that you have installed from them. There is certainly a problem with the github repo. System76 repo should be purged as well.

@OrganicMarble thanks, but I can't figure out how to use ppa-purge on the github entry in /etc/apt/sources-list.d: deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg] https://cli.github.com/packages stable main

I just discovered that GitHub had posted info on expiration of their key, and how to deal with it.  Look at https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/9569
This solves the issue for me.
